# Make sort built-in function

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

gnu make https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#toc-Functions-for-Transforming-Text has sort function. The description for the sort function states that sort function

> Sorts the words of list in lexical order, removing duplicate words. The output is a list of words separated by single spaces.

I created a test makefile like this

```
TEST="this is a test test test test test"

all:

     @echo $(sort $(TEST))
```

My output is **This is a test test**

The duplicates were not entirely removed from the string!
Am I interpreting the sort function incorrectly? Or is it a bug with gnu make?

Comment: Correction the TEST variable is "This is a test test test test"

Comment: Watch the double quotes. `"This is a test test test test"` becomes `"This is a test test"` which the shell prints as `This is a test test`.

Comment: ...It is odd that `sort` doesn't sort within a quoted string, but does remove duplicates therein...

Comment: Your `TEST` variable contains 5 different words: `"this`, `is`, `a`, `test` and `test"`. And only the `test` word is duplicated.

Comment: Agreed that test is duplicate. But there are 3 duplicates. If I would have a string "test test test test" and I would like to remove duplicates I would think that the result would be string "test", do you agree?

Answer (score 2):

The double quotes are in no way special. So the `TEST` variable contains the words `"This`, `is`, `a`, `test`, `test`, `test` and `test"` which are then sorted with duplicate removed as `"This`, `a`, `is`, `test` and `test"` and thus the shell gets(1) `echo "This a is test test"`, interprets the double quote as string markers and outputs `This a is test test` (and not `This is a test test` see the place of the `a`).

---

(1) A useful tip to debug make issue like this is to set the `SHELL` variable to `/bin/echo` so you can see what the shell gets. For instance you'd have had as a result `-c echo "this a is test test"` with the Makefile

```
TEST="this is a test test test test"
SHELL=/bin/echo
all:
    @echo $(sort $(TEST))
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the position of a. But consider a string  "test test test test" Would you not expect the sort function to remove duplicates and the output would be **test** and yet make produces output **test test test**. What is then a definition of **duplicates** in sort function?

Comment: What AProgrammer is trying to point out to you is that _make_ doesn't do anything special with double-quotes.  So, the first "word" in the variable `TEST` is the literal string `"this` (including the double quote).  Similarly, the last word in the variable is the literal string `test"` (including the double quote).  The literal string `test"` is not the same as the literal string `test`, so make won't remove it as a duplicate.  Similarly, when sorting the literal string `"this` the double-quote sorts earlier than all alphabetic chars so that word stays at the start of the result.

Comment: Then when you pass this to `echo` via the shell, the _shell_ will remove the double quotes so you don't see them.  If instead your recipe used single-quotes around the result, like this: `@echo '$(sort $(TEST))'` then you'd see that the double-quotes are still there: make didn't remove them or parse them in any way.  It's just a string to make.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I got it.

Comment: @imendel if you have "got it" please mark the answer up so we know its solved : )